# How do I get android preferences to work?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-activity, radio-button, preferences

Sorry about this guys. This must be like the third question I've had to ask about this project alone. =(

What i want to be able to do is toggle the visibility of a radio button using a check box in a preferences activity.

There are no errors in my code and both activities run fine, but there is no change in visibility when the check box is checked or unchecked.

Here is my Activity with the radiobuttons

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import com.medialets.android.analytics.MMAnalyticsManager;

public class Temperature extends Activity {
MMAnalyticsManager mManager;
private EditText text;

public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onStart();
    getPrefs();
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temperature);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

mManager = MMAnalyticsManager.sharedInstance(this);
mManager.start("codeHere", "1.0",
    false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();

mManager.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

mManager.resume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
mManager.stop();
}






    public void myClickHandler(View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Button01:
            RadioButton celsiustokelvinButton = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.RadioButton05);
            RadioButton celsiustofarenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
            RadioButton farenheittocelsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton02);
            RadioButton farenheittokelvinButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton06);
            RadioButton kelvintocelsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.RadioButton03);
            RadioButton kelvintofarenheitButton=(RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.RadioButton04);
            float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());

              if (celsiustofarenheitButton.isChecked())  {
                text.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFarenheit(inputValue)));
            } if (farenheittocelsiusButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertFarenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
            } if (celsiustokelvinButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertCelsiusToKelvin(inputValue)));
            } if (farenheittokelvinButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertFarenheitToKelvin(inputValue)));
            } if (kelvintocelsiusButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertKelvinToCelsius(inputValue)));
            } if (kelvintofarenheitButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String
                        .valueOf(convertKelvinToFarenheit(inputValue)));
            }
            break;


        }}

    private float convertFarenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit){
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    }
    private float convertCelsiusToFarenheit(float celsius){
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;       
    }
    private double convertCelsiusToKelvin(float celsius){
        return celsius + 273.15;
    }
    private double convertFarenheitToKelvin(float farenheit){
        return ((farenheit-32)/(1.8));
    }
    private double convertKelvinToCelsius(float kelvin){
        return kelvin-273.1;
    }
    private double convertKelvinToFarenheit(float kelvin){
        return kelvin*1.8-459.67;
    }
    boolean CheckboxPreference;


    private void getPrefs() {
            // Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
}

}
```

And here is my Preferences Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;


public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

private RadioButton btn01;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    btn01 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
    Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("customPref");



    customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The Custom Preference Has Been     Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SharedPreferences customSharedPreference =     getSharedPreferences("myCutomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
            editor.putString("myCustomPref","The preference has been clicked");
            editor.commit();

            CheckBox();

            return true;




        }
        private void CheckBox() {
            final CheckBox ThisCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkboxPref);
            ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,boolean     test) {
                    if (ThisCheckBox.isChecked()){ 
                        btn01.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        btn01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });

}}
```

Sorry there is other stuff in there as well such as an analytics plug in

Anyone have any idea as to why this just isn't working

(Just a side note. When looking at the logcat, clicking the checkbox returned no results)

**EDIT:** OK i've just ammended my code as suggested but i'm afraid that the preferences still do not affect anything. Anybody have any ideas?? =(

Comment: Speaking of side notes, when you say, "When looking at the logcat, clicking the checkbox returned no results)", I assume you are viewing it under Eclipse. You do not have to. I prefer viewing it using "adb logcat -v time" to get a much fuller view of what is going on, then filtering or saving the file and viewing with Emacs to make SURE I can see everything that might be relevant. You might want to try that to see if you get more informative logcat output. BTW: you will need more Log.d(), Log.w() etc. function calls sprinkled in the code you show above to figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because for visiblity the values you should use are [(reference)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29):

```
 0 = VISIBLE
 4 = INVISIBLE
 8 = GONE
```

Comment: Yes, and for those you probably should just use the constants to make the code easier to understand. View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this seems to only be part of the answer as the preferences still do not affect the radio button.